# Can't find text element with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use `Selenium` to create a new message in my mailbox. I have a problem with finding `napisz` (en: 'write') button on my e-mail website. I tried to use `driver.find_element_by_link_text` but it doesn't work. I've managed to go workaround this problem using `xpath` but I'm very curious why the first method fails.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://profil.wp.pl/login.html?zaloguj=poczta&url=https://poczta.wp.pl/profil/')
elem_login = browser.find_element_by_name('login_username')
elem_login.send_keys('stack_scraper_wp@wp.pl')
elem_password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
elem_password.send_keys('thankyouforhelp')
elem_zaloguj_button = browser.find_element_by_id('btnSubmit')
elem_zaloguj_button.click()
browser.get('https://poczta.wp.pl/d635/indexgwt.html#start')
elem_napisz_button = browser.find_element_by_link_text('napisz')
elem_napisz_button.click()
```

EDIT: I've tried to used same `xpath` today but it failed. Is it possible that it's somehow dynamic causing the problem?

Comment: What is the exact word written on that button, I meant visible?

Comment: It's "Napisz" :)

Comment: The one you tried within your scraper started with small letter `n`. Can this be a reason?

Comment: My mistake it's all with lowercase letters so it's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find_element_by_link_text()` looks for `a` elements only. In your case, this is the `button` element and cannot be located using this locator.

Comment: It didn't work. I thought that it is exactly 'napisz'. Here's part of the code:     <button class="Button Button--primary" ui-sref="app.compose({type:'new'})" ui-sref-opts="{'inherit':false}" href="#/draft?type=new">napisz</button>

Comment: @PiotrMenclewicz okay, updated the answer as now I can see you posted the actual markup.

Comment: Wasn't familiar with this `a` tag related information @sir alecxe. +1 for this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it. Do you know any other efficient way to search buttons? Is using `xpath` the only way?

Comment: @PiotrMenclewicz I would go the xpath way here and do smth like `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[. = "napisz"]')`.